# html Select Menu change event is not working

Tags: javascript, html

I have a select menu in a form and I want it to edit another select box with the selected value of the first one but the error is, the change event is not working! I checked that the ids are unique, the script is below the form, and I have access to the select menu but the change event don't work any clues why this is happening?

```
 <div id="ecmodal" class="modal">
<span onclick="document.getElementById('ecmodal').style.display='none'" class="close"
  title="Close Modal">&times;</span>
<form id="ecForm" class="modal-content" action="/edit-chapter">
  <div class="container">
    <h1>Edit Chapter</h1>
    <p>Please fill in this form to edit a chapter.</p>
    <hr>

    <input id="inputusername3" type="hidden" name="uname" value="NOTHING" />
    <input id="inputpass3" type="hidden" name="psw" value="NOTHING" />

    <label for="ebooks2"><b>Book Name</b></label>
    <select name="ebooks2" id="ebooks2" form="ecForm" required></select>

    <label for="echapters"><b>Chapter Name</b></label>
    <select name="echapters" id="echapters" form="ecForm" required></select>

    <label for="thumbnail"><b>Chapter Thumbnail</b></label>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Edit Chapter Thumbnail" name="thumbnail" autocomplete="off" required />

    <label for="intro"><b>Chapter Intro</b></label>
    <textarea rows="3" cols="50" name="intro" form="ecForm" required></textarea>

    <label for="credits"><b>Chapter Credits</b></label>
    <textarea rows="3" cols="50" name="credits" form="ecForm" required></textarea>

    <label for="content"><b>Chapter Content</b></label>
    <textarea rows="15" cols="100" name="content" form="ecForm" required></textarea>
    <p>For italicized text use *text* for bold use **text**</p>

    <div class="clearfix">
      <button type="button" onclick="document.getElementById('ecmodal').style.display='none'"
        class="cancelbtn">Cancel</button>
      <button type="submit" class="signupbtn">Edit Chapter</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

event:

```
<script>
alert('onload');
let select = document.getElementById("ebooks2");
console.log(select)
document.getElementById('ebooks2').addEventListener('change', function () {
  alert('Hello');
});

select.addEventListener("input", async function () {
  alert("Change")
  if (select.selectedIndex !== -1) {
    // An option has been selected
    var selectedOption = select.options[select.selectedIndex];
    console.log("Selected option:", selectedOption.value);

    let response = await fetch(`https://novels-production.up.railway.app/data/profileBooks/${selectedOption.value}`);
    let json = await response.json();
    console.log(json)
    if (json) {
      var options = json.chapters.map(v => {
        return {
          "text": v.name,
          "value": v.name
        }
      });

      var selectChaptersBox = document.getElementById('echapters');

      for (var i = 0, l = options.length; i < l; i++) {
        var option = options[i];
        selectChaptersBox.options.add(new Option(option.text, option.value, option.selected));
      }

      alert("This is a test.");
    }
  } else {
    // No option has been selected
    console.log("Please select an option");
  }
});
```

Comment: By any chance you only have one option to select in ebooks2 ?

Comment: Unclear question. Your code isn't functioning well. Try add image of before and after you want to achieve.

Comment: You have no options in the ebooks2 select... The ebooks2 event listener does nothing but display an alert box saying 'Hello', delete this part of the code... In the line where it says  select.addEventListener("input", async function () {, change "input" to "change"

Comment: your code seems working fine at first sight, however you don't have any options to select. Could you add some select options to let us debug your code?

Comment: I have one option to select